# Print variable value out of foreach loop in php without page refreshing

Tags: php, foreach

I am using curl php get result in return variable.i am using for each loop for retrieving all  key value in return variable and print i got all value through indexing .here all is fine but i'm trying to 6th no value store in $_SESSION['date'] variable and echo it outside the function .first time when i run page it will not print $_SESSION['date'].but when we refresh the page it will print.please give me solution.thank you my code is
i want to print date in div without page refresh.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="head"> <?php echo $_SESSION['date']; ?></div>
  <?php
  function curlUsingGet($url, $data)
  {
  if(empty($url) OR empty($data))
  {
    return 'Error: invalid Url or Data';
  }

  $fields_string = '';
  foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&'; }
  rtrim($fields_string,'&');

  $urlStringData = $url.'?'.$fields_string;
  $_SESSION['urlStringData']=$urlStringData;
  $cookie= "cookie.txt";
  $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$urlStringData);

   $return = curl_exec($ch);
   $arrel = explode('|',$return);

foreach($arrel as $val)
    {
    $new_el=explode('~',$val);
    print"<ul data-role=listview  data-icon=false style=margin-top:3%;>";
    print" <li >";
    print"<a href='causelistmsg.php?a=$new_el[3]&b=$new_el[4]'>";
    print"<font class=alignleft size='3' style=color:#FFFF00;>";
    echo $new_el[0]; 
    print"</font>";
    print"<font size='3' class=aligncenter style=color:#FF8000;>";
    echo $new_el[2];
    print"</font>";
    print"<font class=alignright size='3' style=color:#00CC00;>";
    echo $new_el[1]; 
    print"</font>";
    print"</a>";
    print" </li >";
    print" </ul>";
    $_SESSION['date'] = $new_el[6];
    curl_close($ch);
    }

    $_SESSION['date'];
    $data = array('u' =>$_SESSION['councel']);
    echo curlUsingGet('http://"url"/causelist/CauseListData',$data);
 ?>
```

Comment: where you call session_start() ?

Comment: very first i call session_start(); before doc type

Comment: you should start session with `session_start()` at the top of the page.

Comment: yes sir i start session_start at first

Comment: here all is fine but when i am trying to print $_SESSION['date'] in out of foreach loop means top of page in div it will not print when page first time run.but when i refresh the page it will print date.

Comment: how i print date out of for each loop when page first time run

Answer (score 0):

You first call `echo $_SESSION['date']` and only then assign it a value;

What you should do is get all your logic done before you actually start output, i. e. your `foreach($arrel as $val)` part should just populate an array.

Btw. You set your `$_SESSION['data']` inside `foreach` cycle, so it's getting rewritten several times. Is that normal, or it is indeed a logic flaw?

Comment: sir i want to retrieve date from new_el[6] and print at the top of page in div.

Comment: when we store new_el[6] in $_SESSION['date'] and print echo in div it gives correct value but after page refresh.but i want echo date when page was first run

Comment: Look, your problem is, you first do a `<?php echo $_SESSION['date']; ?>` and only then `$_SESSION['date']` is given a value on the first run.